# Mass flow rate and force on moving disk

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics

If I understood correctly, the force $F$ related to a given mass flow rate $\dot{m}$ through orifice area $A$ (or, say, on a disk of area $A$) is given by Newton's 2nd law of motion - assuming a constant velocity - with

\begin{align}
\vec{F} &= \tfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} \left( m \vec{v} \right) \\
  &= \tfrac{\mathrm{d} m}{\mathrm{d} t} \vec{v} \\
  &= \dot{m} \vec{v} = \rho A \vec{v}^2
\end{align}

I am wondering what would happen if the area $A$ itself would be moving with a constant velocity $\vec{v}_0$ along the direction of $\dot{m}$.

If we assume

\begin{align}
\vec{v}_{rel} &= \vec{v} - \vec{v}_0
\end{align}

would it be correct to say

\begin{align}
\vec{F} &= \dot{m} \vec{v}_{rel}  \\
        &= \rho A \vec{v} \, \vec{v}_{rel} \\
        &= \rho A \left( \vec{v}^2 - \vec{v} \,\vec{v}_0 \right)
\end{align}

that is, the mass flow rate is still $\rho A v$ but the relative velocity of the disk is $v - v_0$?

Or should it be
\begin{align}
\vec{F} &= \rho A \vec{v}^2_{rel} \\
        &= \rho A \left( \vec{v}^2 - 2 \vec{v} \,\vec{v}_0 + \vec{v}^2_0 \right)
\end{align}

that is, the mass flow rate being $\rho A v_{rel}$?

Also, is this mathematically correct? It feels kind of weird to apply the Hadamard/Schur product to the velocity vectors just to obtain another velocity in the same direction.

Comment: Not my area of expertise but I have to believe that in the frame of reference of the disk, only the relative velocity cm can matter. The answer should be independent of frame of reference.

Comment: That does make sense indeed.

Comment: It is actually the second answer, with relative mass flow that is correct.
But your point of departure is questionable: it is an open system and you have to do a careful balance of momentum (Reynolds formula).

Answer (score 1):

The second one as the mass flow rate also changes from Relative frame of reference

Comment: This could be a potentially good answer, if you fleshed it out a bit.